# GAE NDB "Result cannot be set twice" error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I hit this *Result cannot be set twice* Runtime error on GAE Ndb async queries when doing `ndb.Future.wait_all(futures)` on a bunch of async queries.

Something like this:

```
futures = []
for item in items:
    item._future_get = MyEntity.query(...).get_async()
    futures.append(item._future_get)

ndb.Future.wait_all(futures)
# ...
```

It fails on the `wait_all` with *Result cannot be set twice*

This error message is nowhere mentionned on SO.  Google has 2-3 mentions of it dating back to 2011, and with no clear explanation.

More info:

items are ndb entities from a previous fetch.  But they don't really matter here (at least I think), since the query is performed on MyEntity.   I am used to attaching futures to the object they relate to in this way, so it's easier to sort out when all have completed.

The stack trace:

```
  File "/home/my_project/app/main/admin/my_module.py", line 166, in admin_base_cleanup_details ndb.Future.wait_all(futures)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 350, in wait_all ev.run1()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/eventloop.py", line 235, in run1 delay = self.run0()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/eventloop.py", line 197, in run0 callback(*args, **kwds)
INFO     2016-04-26 08:40:04,152 module.py:808] default: "GET /admin/cleanup/details?mode=status HTTP/1.1" 500 -
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 475, in _on_future_completion self._help_tasklet_along(ns, ds_conn, gen, val)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 386, in _help_tasklet_along self.set_result(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 265, in set_result
    raise RuntimeError('Result cannot be set twice.')
RuntimeError: Result cannot be set twice.
```

Some more precisions:

- Yes, it does happen on GAE as well as on local dev.
- No, it does not fail every single time, but often enough.

I found it has to do with concurrency from another thread.  The web page started 2 requests through ajax calls:  one for an update query with some async calls, that would take quite a few seconds, and another one like a periodic status update, quicker but also with async calls.  It is the latter that failed, not always but very often.   Since then, I avoided overlapping the two requests and it stopped failing.  It still seems like a bug, since overlapping requests is not something forbidden.

Comment: You don't mention what `item` is nore which line gets the exception,  so could _future_get be a modifiable attribute and item is duplicated in item ?

Comment: You should include the stack trace, and a bit more info about what an `item` is.

Comment: @Tim I added more info to the initial question.

Comment: Is the issue intermittent or does it happen every single time? And does it happen if you upload it to App Engine?

Comment: Also, can you isolate it to a block of code that can be run outside of your application by us? I was thinking maybe if you had a duplicate item in your list, but alas, no dice. So I'm at a loss.

Comment: Thank you for your time and efforts @Ken.  I have tried to add the answers into the original question.

Comment: It does indeed sound like it could be some kind of race condition. You could, of course, run this in a transaction (assuming all entities belong to the same entity group), to avoid the race condition. EDIT: OR, use single-threaded application servers.

Comment: Also, I'm assuming items objects are never shared between threads?

Answer (score 1):

You are using get_async() which "Asynchronously returns the first query result", whereas you should probably use fetch_async() to get a Future.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queryclass#Query_get_async

Comment: I believe get_async() _does return a future_, although it is true that the documentation you are referring to does not state this explicitly.   How else would it be asynchronous if it returned not a future but an entity ?

Comment: You are right. ndb.get_async() indeed returns a future. What you are describing as the problem source is quite interesting. Perhaps a look into tasklets could provide a more concrete solution, without the need to avoid overlapping requests.